# How can I create a password only login form?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

Trying to reconfigure a login that originally required a username and password to login, to just accepting a password to login - for reasons I'm not going to go into. I continually get the default error 'Invalid Password' when trying to login. This is just for a concept so please disregard any security holes etc, just trying to gain access using a password only.

Ta.

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {

    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);

    $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT user_id, password FROM tbl_users WHERE password='$password'");
    $row=$query->fetch_array();

    $count = $query->num_rows;

    if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) && $count==1) {
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    } else {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> 
&nbsp; Invalid Password !
                </div>";
    }
    $DBcon->close();
}
```

Comment: Is the password still going to be linked to a user?

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` somewhere in your script? Also you can't select anything via the password cause you're trying to compare a plain text password (*readable*) against a hash

Comment: `WHERE password='$password'` will never be true, because you have a hashed password in database and the user is sending plain text.

Comment: @Ajaypayne the password will still be linked to a user and their session logged eventually.

Comment: @Darren session_start() is included but I see what you mean about the plain password then a hashed although the password is being hashed when the user registers.

Comment: So you *should* just be able to remove username from both the input and the SQL query that you already have

Comment: "This is just for a concept so please disregard any security holes etc..." Write secure code to **start** with. Among other things, in this *particular* case it's not *possible* to write it in the insecure way - you can't do a `SELECT WHERE` against a bcrypt hash like the ones `password_hash` puts out, as the hash changes every time. "I can't be bothered to write it securely" here means writing it twice.

Comment: @ceejayoz I could end up writing it a million times, who cares! The more I write, the more I learn as I only started learning PHP a month ago.

Comment: @RayVM That's the problem. Writing bad code means you're *practicing* writing bad code, which means a) sometimes it slips into production and b) it's harder to unlearn. There is no good reason to knowingly write insecure code.

Comment: password hash is unique even in same passwords. That database query won't work. You better query with a username or email, then do password_verify(..) on the passed password and the retrieve database password.

Comment: I can't get this to work at all. Security is not an issue here as it will never see the outside world, just an internal form for 40 employees to quickly access and update on a tablet. I thought a 6 digit pin would work well as I'm dealing with employees who can barely use a phone, so a 6 digit pin made sense as it's how they access their phone. Trying to make it quick and easy. Perhaps a drop down of their usernames for identification, then type their password for authentication? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if two users use the same password... ( $count>1 )